# struts 2.1 book?

Tags: java, struts2

Struts 2.1 is a major upgrade from the previous 2.0.X versions.

I have not been able to find any books for Struts2.1 or ref guides.  There is a [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg87489.html)  on Struts mailing list but I think Manning has canceled the publication [Struts2.1 book](http://www.manning.com/wannemacher/)

Does anyone know of Struts books being released that cover Struts2.1 in details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Struts community does not agree that it is a major upgrade.  At least they do not think anyone would like to pay to learn about the upgrade.

The best resource is likely to be a Struts 2.0 book and [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html) upgrade guide.